# django-rosetta error: You can't use the CacheRosettaStorage

Tags: python, django, django-rosetta

I'm using django-rosetta app, it works on development without a CACHES setting, but on prod I've this setting as follow:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    }
}
```

The problem is that under prod it raises me

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:
You can't use the CacheRosettaStorage if your cache isn't correctly set up, 
please double check your Django DATABASES setting and that the cache server is responding
```

The database setting is simple as

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as the exception message sais:

> double check your Django DATABASES setting and that the cache server is responding

I did it, even my memchached was working correctly I decided reinstall it, and, as magic art, it worked!

Before that I changed my CACHES

```
CACHES = {
 'default': {
    'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
    'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
 },
 'rosetta': {
    'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
    'LOCATION': '/var/tmp/django_cache',
 }
}
```

Django rosetta will use a key **rosetta** if a cache with this name exists, or **default** if not. With the FileBasedCache it wasn't launch any error, so I realized the problem was with MemcachedCache. But, after reinstall it, it worked.